# Probability to really be the best in a boolean game

Tags: probability

I was wondering of something special after saw some Kasparov chess parties, how to be sure he was the best when he won championships.

---

Let consider a set of $2^n$ players of a "boolean" game. What i mean by boolean is that you can win or lose but never make a draw. I assume that chess is not a boolean game, but do it like it was, but the game may also be tennis or whatever you want.

Now let consider all players have $0.5$ lucky to win or lose against all other players. Because when $n$ is big its impossible in real to a player to play against all others, in first step they will do $n/2$ parties, and $n/2$ players will lose and will be eliminate, the same again and again $n$ times to know "who is the best".

I am wondering what is the probability this player really is the best player? Because he may lost againt an other player he didn't play during all parties.

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: normally the best player has better odds of winning a match than 50-50.

Answer (score 1):

If you are assuming there is a 50-50 chance of winning regardless of who is playing, then I would hardly call anyone "the best". But by the symmetry of the problem all players are equally likely to come out as the winner, so the probability that "the best" actually wins is $1/2^n$.